# Not Getting the Query String from $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php, http, http-referer

I'm trying to get the Query String from Search Engines like Google, Bing, and Yahoo to store them in my database and show the keyword being used to get my site in the search engine on that specific page.

I have checked every Global variable of PHP ($_SERVER, $_REQUEST, $_POST, $_GET, $_GLOBAL and $_COOKIE) but could not find the required data.

I want "bill+hicks+sporting+goods+wholesale" in "https://www.bing.com/search?q=bill+hicks+sporting+goods+wholesale&qs=n&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=bill+hicks+sporting+goods+wholesale&sc=2-35&sk=&cvid=9E5D9E7C0B5B4740A42B5758CCE510D0"

The following code was working before but now all of the search engines have stopped sending the query string in HTTP_REFERER.

```
function get_search_query() {
    $ref_keywords = '';
    // Get the referrer to the page
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (!empty($referrer))
    {
        //Parse the referrer URL
        $parts_url = parse_url($referrer);
        // Check if a query string exists
        $query = isset($parts_url['query']) ? $parts_url['query'] : '';
        if($query)
        {
            // Convert the query string into array
            parse_str($query, $parts_query);
            // Check if the parameters 'q' or 'query' exists, and if exists that is our search query terms.
            $ref_keywords = isset($parts_query['q']) ? $parts_query['q'] : (isset($parts_query['query']) ? $parts_query['query'] : '' );
        }
    }
    return $ref_keywords;
}
```

code from https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/get-search-query-string-from-search-engines-using-php/

Comment: If they've stopped sending it then you can't get it, can you? I think that already answers the question...

Comment: Sites can send whatever value they like for the referrer field (or even no value at all)...it's not something you can ever rely on

Comment: @ADyson I know. But there must be any workaround of this. How could we get the same information now? There should be a way to get the keyword for which our website comes up in the search engine.

Comment: "But there must be any workaround" ...must there? You can only get the information if the search engine decides to provide it to you. I believe Google and others would prefer you to use their analytics tools to get information about visitors to your site

Comment: Also, a couple of questions: 1) does your PHP site use HTTP or HTTPS (or does it even allow both)? This can sometimes affect what referrer information is available to you. 2) you mention it was "working before" ...before what? When exactly did it stop working? Did you make any changes to your site around this time?

Comment: @ADyson the sites use HTTP and I changed the code from core PHP to Phalcon framework. It's not even working on core PHP code. I believe there is nothing wrong with my code. 

I just want to know if this could be achieved from some other methods? Like fetching data from Google Analytics API.

Comment: And how long ago exactly did it stop working for you? Bing in particular talked about removing the querystring information 4 years ago... https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2015/06/15/bing-moving-to-encrypt-search-traffic-by-default . The others made similar moves around the same sort of time, from what I can gather reading about it online

Comment: Also you should consider hosting your site with HTTPS instead - very often search engines will also not pass referrer information from their HTTPS site to your HTTP site, because it's considered not secure over HTTP (and therefore the content of what their users are searching for could be leaked). Not to mention these days you can improve your search engine ranking, your users' confidence about your site, and generally reduce other security risks by using HTTPS. The whole world is moving in this direction.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry I missed the "s". The site uses HTTPs not HTTP.